# How do I turn off Gmail application passwords?

Tags: gmail, two-factor-authentication

I've got the other 2FA choices turned on - Google app ping on my phone, Google Authenticator App, SMS... but I'm still stuck with creating app passwords for desktop email programs.

I had to activate it when I was playing with `neomutt` on my Linux machine, which obviously can't display the Google OAuth popup window. But I cannot find where to turn it off.

Please make it stop!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure all those other apps are capable of speaking OAuth?

Comment: Yep, it's Geary on Linux. It's a modern app, so I presume it would be clever enough to show the OAuth popup.

Comment: I found my own answer. It's a GNOME app that I'm trying to run on a KDE desktop. It apparently depends on a bunch of GNOME dependencies for OAuth to work. I'm either stuck with the app passwords or I find a different client.